# LanguageApp.translate limits

Tags: google-apps-script, quota

I have been trying to research the amount of times I can call LanguageApp.translate per day in a Google Apps Script but I cannot seem to find a concrete answer. Most places I look direct me to https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas but it isn't clear to me which feature this falls under.

We are currently hitting our daily limit of calls most days and I wanted to look into ways of increasing the amount of calls or, if that was not an option, looking into other options such as Google Translation API.

Thanks for the help in advance!